# Door Bell transformer box

Tags: kitchens

My door bell transformer is on an outside wall in my ceiling. I want to know if I can put the whole thing with the wire behind the drywall?  Concerned about it over heating. [image]

Comment: Definite duplicate- posting the same question twice is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That bell transformer mounts on a mains power electrical box. The electrical code requires that all electrical boxes remain accessible and not be enclosed. This means that you will also not be able to cover over the box + transformer behind drywall.

You may have the option to move the bell transformer to a completely different location and re-run the low voltage wires to the doorbell. Then you could just insulate the wire ends in the box and cover this existing electrical box with blank cover which you then paint to a color to match the wall there by the ceiling. The result would be much less of an eyesore than the transformer hanging there with it's exposed wires.

Comment: I want to move the transformer because I’m opening up the enclosed ceiling space and it’s ugly. It seems my only option is to just disconnect. Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score -2):

You can buy a deep box 4 x 4that fits into the wall has a cover and then use a chase nipple to attach for the electrical.

Comment: Still doesn't let you bury it behind drywall...